# How to handle loop from 0 to 2^95?

Tags: loops

my problem is as follows:

I have to iterate through all possibilities (0 or 1) of 95 elements.

For example if there were 2 elements, possibilities would be:
00, 01, 10, 11

Number of total possibilities is 2^n, so it grows very fast. 
2^95 = 39614081257132168796771975168

How would I effectively iterate from 0 to 2^95?

P.S. Choice of programming language is not vital, but I guess C or C++ should be the fastest choices.

P.P.S. I thought as BigInt implementations seem to be considerably slower than primitive types, it may be a good idea to split the number into X number of primitives. I had no luck so far though.

P.P.S. I have a function which would generate possibility by supplying a number from 0 to 2^95

Comment: what's your CPU model then

Comment: I like you, you're funny.

Comment: What do you need to do with these numbers? That seems like a fairly fundamental aspect of the problem. Do you want a file with them all in? Do you need to pass each of them in turn to some other library or program?

Comment: Well it looks like you've basically got two problems. First it looks like you are saying you want to find every possible value of a very large number so you need to use a very large word length for that. Second it sounds like you are asking if there is a fast way to do something that might take a very long time and there's not. Also as @IMSoP is asking you did not really say what it is you want to do with these numbers. For example if you don't care if the loop control holds the complete number you can nest loops. Two nested loops that each run 2^64 times will yield 2^128 iterations.

Comment: Yes, as @Radiodef said, use nested loops.

Comment: “I thought as BigInt implementations seem to be considerably slower than primitive types” You are really funny. A 1GHz CPU cycle lasts 1 nanosecond. Ask yourself this question: how much time do 2^95 nanoseconds represent?

Comment: “91 * universe age”, courtesy of http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E95+nanoseconds

Comment: +1 for just being totally ignorant of the fact how large some numbers are.

Comment: You *don't* need to iterate from 0 to 2^95. You need to figure out what you really need to do instead. Generating random numbers in that range might be reasonable, but you won't cover more than a tiny fraction of the range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modern CPUs run at a few GigaHertz, so you *might* be able to iterate over one billion values per second (if you're not doing much else).

At one billion iterations per second, it would take you over 1.2 trillion years to reach 2<sup>95</sup> iterations.

You need to find a different way to do whatever you're doing.

Comment: Haha, nice! I guess that's where I should have started (and ended). Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a quantum computer, you can't escape from iterating through the entire range. The simplest would be to split the 95 bits into a set of primitives. For example, if your system operates with 64-bit numbers, you can take 2 of those.
The pseudo-code will be something like this:

```
lowBound <-- 2^64-1
highBound <-- 2^31-1
for highIdx = 0 up to highBound
    for lowIdx = 0 up to lowBound
         ; Do your thing here, if you need the actual index,
         ; it's combinable from lowIdx and highIdx
```

The fastest would be to use `Assembly` with architecture-specific instructions to better utilize the system resources for process speeding up (registers, cache etc.). You can also consider using GPUs - they are very good in parallellizing tasks, thus if your operation is similar for each iteration it can have a good performance.

**However, all of this is pretty useless and you should devise a better algorithm for what you're doing instead of iteration, like noted in @KeithThompson 's answer**.

Answer (score 2):

In *theory*, here is what you do:

```
int exp = 95;

UInt64 hmax = 2 ^ (exp - 64);
UInt64 lmax = 2 ^ 63 + (2 ^ 63 - 1);

for (UInt64 high = 0; high < hmax; high++) {
    for (UInt64 low = 0; low <= lmax; low++) {

        // do stuff

    }
}
```

Now the loop control `high` holds the high word and loop control `low` holds the low word. Now you can do something like this:

```
// where UInt128 is your big integer type
// cast the high word to prevent overflow

UInt128 word = (UInt128)high << 64 | low;
```

Or concatenate them as strings.

The loop pattern looks like this (using bytes for representation):

```
00000000 00000000
00000000 00000001
00000000 00000010

and eventually you get to

00000000 11111111

inner loop completes and it goes to

00000001 00000000
00000001 00000001
```

Comment: You overflow in your `lmax` on initialization

Comment: @icepack Yeah you're right. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you will need qubits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit) to do your calculations, but as they are theoretical in nature, maybe it's best that you start your iterating now, and see if it will be faster or quantum computing will get your answer quickly.

Using quantum computing, you would be able to test ALL of the combinations at once.

Start reading here, it might not solve your problem, but it sure is interesting: http://physics.about.com/od/physicsqtot/g/quantumparallel.htm

Comment: Starting the computation now won't do any good. I expect that improved hardware over the next, say, ten years will knock much more than ten years off the expected run time, so a better strategy is to sit and wait. (It would be interesting to compute the ideal starting point, but you'd have to make some assumptions about the rate of hardware improvement; it's not clear that Moore's Law will hold up indefinitely.)